# VBA data validation works in the VBE but not in Deactivate event

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to have a dropdown so employees won't make a mistake in entering details. This is through the use of data validation feature of excel.

When I run this script in the VBE (<kbd>F5</kbd> key), the script works with no problem.

But when I place it in the `Deactivate` event of a worksheet, it errors at one point.

The error occurs on this line:

```
Worksheets("Input").Range("C" & i7).Select
```

In this code block:

```
Dim Total_rows_Dash7 As Long
Dim Total_rows_Active7 As Long
Dim Total_rows_Input7 As Long
Dim i7 As Long
Dim j7 As Long
Dim m7 As Long

Total_rows_Dash7 = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i7 = 2 To Total_rows_Dash7
    m7 = 0
    Total_rows_Active7 = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Active Jobs").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j7 = 2 To Total_rows_Active7
        If Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(i7, 2) = Worksheets("Active Jobs").Cells(j7, 1) Then
            m7 = 1
        End If
    Next j7
    If m7 = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Active Jobs").Cells(Total_rows_Active7 + 1, 1) = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(i7, 2)
    End If
Next i7

Total_rows_Active7 = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Active Jobs").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_Input7 = Workbooks("Hourly Production Monitoring.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For i7 = 2 To Total_rows_Input7
    Worksheets("Input").Range("C" & i7).Select '<-- error occurs here
        With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="='Active Jobs'!$A$2:$A$" & Total_rows_Active7 & ""
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next i7
```

The error is as shown below:

> Run time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed

[image]

Comment: Does it highlight in yellow the error line if you step through the code pressing F8?

Comment: It highlights in yellow, then after I press another F8 that error pops out

Comment: That means you are not on Input Sheet when trying to select a range on that sheet. Actually you don't need to select the range and still you can perform all those actions on the target range.

Comment: Yes that was my guess as well. But when I try to change the code from: `Worksheets("Input").Range("C" & i7).Select` to `Worksheets("Input").Range("C" & i7)` then With `Selection.Validation` to With `Range.Validation` it errors. I believe it has something to do with my usage of the `With-End With`. I never use it. Can you suggest how I should revise?

Comment: errors on what line? With what message?

Comment: It's noted on the main post. However solution is already found by @sktneer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per what I suggested in the comments, you may give this a try...

```
For i7 = 2 To Total_rows_Input7
     With Worksheets("Input").Range("C" & i7).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="='Active Jobs'!$A$2:$A$" & Total_rows_Active7 & ""
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next i7
```

Comment: Yup that works fine. Thank you! I used a macro to get this code out so i'm not quite sure how to revise it